# Plot Gantt-like plot from csv

Tags: pgfplots, pgfgantt, csv

I am trying to plot a Gantt-like chart with pgfplot from a CSV-File.
The aim is to display the behavoir of a task scheduler. In my CSV-File I have tupel of timestamp(x) and task ID(y).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x,y
8868932,10
8868949,9
8868985,10
8868995,34
8869924,4
8869969,10
8869987,9
8870023,10
8870033,18
8870043,34
8870915,1
8870949,4
8871062,10
8871079,9
8871115,10
8871125,23
8871147,34
8871890,4
8871920,10
8871937,9
8871973,10
8871983,26
8872878,10
8872896,9
8872932,10
8872941,11
8872980,26
8873862,10
8873879,9
8873915,10
8873925,18
8873935,26
8874281,34
8874632,26
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily \footnotesize
]
\begin{axis}[
    grid = major,
    scaled ticks=false,
    symbolic y coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34},
ytick={1,...,34},
height=12cm,
width=15cm,
x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
]
\addplot[
        only marks,
        mark=square, 
        scatter,
    ] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Every data point indicates which task was active. But instead to show only the point the task was scheduled I like to display the period of time the task was active. So the mark at each point needs to have a width relative to the differnce of the next timestamp and this timestamp.
Is there any possibility to do this with pgfplot?
Or do you have any other idea to display a gantt-like chart with this given data?

Thank you very much

Comment: I still don't quite understand the intended result. Could you please explain in more detail? For example, given these `8868932,10
8868949,9
8868985,10
8868995,34
8869924,4
8869969,10` six rows in your data table, what would be the expected outcome?

Comment: Just to clarify, what I don't fully understand is how the width for the bars is calculated.

Comment: Hello Gonzalo, the width for the first dataset will be 8868949 - 8868932 = 17. So Task-ID 10 was 17 ticks active. And 17 should be the width of the bar. The width of the next tuple will be 8868985 - 8868949 = 36 which is the number of ticks for Task 9 and so on.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simplified solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using the `jump mark left` plot (a variant of `const plot` without lines); one problem is that the some of the widths will be too short compared to the data, so even with a 30cm width plot some of the intervals are difficult to see:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x,y
8868932,10
8868949,9
8868985,10
8868995,34
8869924,4
8869969,10
8869987,9
8870023,10
8870033,18
8870043,34
8870915,1
8870949,4
8871062,10
8871079,9
8871115,10
8871125,23
8871147,34
8871890,4
8871920,10
8871937,9
8871973,10
8871983,26
8872878,10
8872896,9
8872932,10
8872941,11
8872980,26
8873862,10
8873879,9
8873915,10
8873925,18
8873935,26
8874281,34
8874632,26
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily \footnotesize
]
\begin{axis}[
  grid = major,
  scaled ticks=false,
  thick,
  ytick={1,...,34},
  height=12cm,
  width=30cm,
  x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
]
\addplot+[jump mark left] table[col sep=comma]{data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to **skevin93** for [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266352/3954).